# Html Tags not working in Cakephp Mail

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3

I'm using cakephp2.4.5 & I have created view as:

```
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?> <?php echo $this->Form->create('Feedback', array('controller' => 'Feedbacks', 'action' => 'sendmail'));
        echo $this->Form->email('mail',array('label' => false,'required' => true,'class'=>'form__in form__in--text form-control','placeholder'=>__('E-mail'),'div'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->textarea('message',array('label' => false,'required' => true,'class'=>'form__in form__in--textarea form-control','placeholder'=>__('Message'),'div'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->submit('Send', array('label' => 'Send', 'class' => 'form__submit', ));
        echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Created controller as:

```
public function sendmail() {
$usertopic = "Form";
$useremail = $this->data['Feedback']['mail'];
$usermessage = $this->data['Feedback']['message'];


$message = '<b>Hi:</b>' . $usermessage . "\r\n" . '<b>Your Message is:</b> ' . $useremail;

if(CakeEmail::deliver('example@gmail.com', $usertopic, $message, array('from' => $useremail)))
{
 $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Feedback has been sent'),'flash',array('alert'=>'success'));
 return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'index'));
}
```

The output will be

```
<b>Hi:</b> XYZ 
<b>Your Message is:</b> Something
```

Can anyone please help me how to send an email without those HTML tags in message body. Any suggestion will appreciate thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please help me how to send an email with out those HTML tags in message body.

Is that your code? Guess no because it doesn't look like you've bothered to read it.

```
$message = '<b>Hi:</b>' . $usermessage . "\r\n" . '<b>Your Message is:</b> ' . $useremail;
```

You or someone else added the `<b>` tags there! Just remove them.

Also [use templates](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails), this is pretty ugly mixing of view related code with a controller. Read the documentation about the [CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the quick method for sending email of cakePHP. Use the standard way to send email and set the email format to solve your HTML tags issue. Try this..

```
public function sendmail() {
    $usertopic = "Form";
    $useremail = $this->data['Feedback']['mail'];
    $usermessage = $this->data['Feedback']['message'];

    $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';  // both = html + plain text (email format)
    $this->Email->to = 'example@gmail.com';
    $this->Email->subject = $usertopic;  
    $message = '<b>Hi:</b>' . $usermessage . "\r\n" . '<b>Your Message is:</b> ' . $useremail;

    if($this->Email->send($message)){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Feedback has been sent'),'flash',array('alert'=>'success'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'index'));
    } 
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: EmailComponent was deprecated in 2.0, could do with showing the correct configuration and usage of CakeEmail.